# Restricting openldap ldapsearch on attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have the following query against my directory:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://example.com -D "cn=gitlab,ou=Service Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -w foobar -b "ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com"
```

With the following olcAccess I get following results:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to dn.subtree="ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com" by dn="cn=gitlab,ou=Service Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" read
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self =xw by anonymous auth
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read by * none
```

(rule 1 should be first and it also works like that, but to be sure, I put it down for now)

Result:

```
# Persons, example.com
dn: ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Persons

# Hans Wurst, Persons, example.com
dn: cn=Hans Wurst,ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com
givenName: Hans
sn: Wurst
cn: Hans Wurst
uid: hwurst
userPassword:: <PASSWORDHASH>
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 500
homeDirectory: /home/hwurst
loginShell: /bin/bash
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top

# Carla Kaese, Persons, example.com
dn: cn=Carla Kaese,ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com
gidNumber: 500
givenName: Carla
homeDirectory: /home/ckaese
loginShell: /bin/bash
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
sn: Kaese
uid: ckaese
uidNumber: 1000
cn: Carla Kaese
userPassword:: <PASSWORDHASH>
```

Now **my goal is** to restrict the read access to only some attributes. Thus I change the acls as followes:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to dn.subtree="ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com" attrs="entry,uid,cn" by dn="cn=gitlab,ou=Service Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" read
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self =xw by anonymous auth
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read by * none
```

I added `attrs="entry,uid,cn"`

However, the same search now just returns:

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? How can it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
olcAccess: {0}to dn.children="ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com" attrs=entry,uid,cn,userPassword,mail by dn="cn=gitlab,ou=Service Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" tls_ssf=128 read by * none break
olcAccess: {1}to dn.subtree="ou=Persons,dc=example,dc=com" by dn="cn=gitlab,ou=Service Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" tls_ssf=128 search by * none break
```

Michael Ströder was close. I needed an extra `search`. Additionally, the `break` was necessary. Apparently otherwise the evaluation already stops before the tree can be iterated down to the correct entries.

The `tls_ssf=128` is not necessary for this problem, but adds an additional level of security.

Answer (score 1):

ACLs also affect the authentication step.

When using simple bind (with DN and password) you have to grant *auth* right to attributes *entry* and *userPassword* on the entry to be authenticated.

But AFAICS your last ACL effectively blocks auth access to pseudo-attribute *entry*. I'd try as last ACL (not tested):

```
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read by * auth
```